# How do I determine what is causing a redirect for a given page?

Tags: redirect, template-redirect

This is probably a face palm question. On Wordpress 4.4. the link

```
http://example.com/blog
```

...redirects to:

```
http://example.com/category/general
```

...ie. it's redirecting to archive.php and displaying all posts in the category 'general'.

And I cannot figure out -why-. Is there a way to get a 'trace' of the redirections?

The .htaccess is the standard WP code. I have no redirection plug-ins. I have no redirect function calls in functions.php. I have disabled all plug-ins but Yoast 3.11.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not a face palm question at all.  When you say "it's redirecting to archive.php" can you elaborate?   Archive.php is a page template, not a destination URL.   There may be multiple issues at work here, confusing your path to a solution.

Comment: 'general' is the default category, isn't it?

Comment: @TungDu Yes, 'general' is the default category.

Comment: @jdm2112 Again, when the visitor types example.com/blog (which is a Page with the permalink 'blog'), instead the visitor goes to example.com/category/general. So somewhere /blog is being redirected to use the archive template instead of the -Page- I created. I want to know how to figure out -why-.

Comment: you can trace first from `redirect_canonical` https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/canonical.php#L41

Comment: Use the [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) plugin to find the specific rewrite rule that is causing the redirect. Post the rule here so we can better help you.

Comment: Do you have XDebug installed? I would recommend this; you can then simply follow the PHP-functions of the request, and see where it quits; you can then even see the variable-values at this stage.